# Using single Time Series per Device containing multiple sensors in Azure Timeseries Insights

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

We are using Azure TimeSeries Insights to store time series from various sensors from our devices.
In order to faciliate querying of multiple related sensors at once i only use the deviceId (from IoT Hub) as a TimeSeries Id.
This works for my backend queries and i can use the filter expression to filter by sensor id.

The only downside i discovered was that i am losing support for TSI Explorer because my value property in a time series contains values from multiple sensors. Display as a single graph makes no sense.

I thought maybe i can use the TSI Model to create fields which filter by sensor id so i get the same experience in TSI Explorer as if i would use a time series per device and sensor. But i didn't figure out how to do so.

So my questions are:

- Does the approach of merging multiple sensors of a device in a single time series have any downsides (besides the apparently lost TSI Explorer support) ?
- Is there a way to model the Time Series to get back TSI Explorer support back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Markus, I am sure adding variable with a filter expression like "$event.sensorId.String = ''", will allow plotting time series on TSI explorer. However this would have a serious performance implications; especially when you have a large number of time series instances.

The most preferred method is to model each sensor (using composite TSID) as a time series and build hierarchy model to organize/contextualize data such that sensors are listed under a device as a parent in TSI explorer.

From TSI team, we would like to better understand your use case. If I may suggest something, please raise a support ticket in Azure portal with necessary contact details. we can get in touch to understand your use case here and better assist you in attaining your objective.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It would be great to get in touch about this use-case. Should i link to this SO question or is there any other reference to include in the Support Ticket to make sure it ends up at the right place?

Comment: @MarkusS. adding this SO and your contact details will help us to schedule a time for us to get together on this.